# Get MS Access table creation script in C#?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, scripting, create-table

Is is possible to get Ms Access Table script using C# ?

Although there is a [tool](http://dbweigher.com/dbwscript.php) that does this.
I was thinking if there is any automatic way to get the script of table .

Till now I am using

```
using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo))
{
    ret = reader.GetSchemaTable();                        
}
```

to get the schema of the table

Can we get creation script of access datatable in C# ?

Thank you All

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the script using the schema information, looping through columns getting the properties etc. Below is just adding column and datatype, but should be extended if the table is more intricate.

```
DataTable dt = reader.GetSchemaTable();
string query;
List<string> list = new List<string>();

foreach (DataRow columns in dt.Rows)
{
   foreach (DataColumn properties in dt.Columns)
   {
       list.Add(properties.ColumnName + " " + properties.DataType);
   }
}

query = string.Join(",", list);
```

Then build your string for the execute query.

```
Create Table [TableName] (
   [append string here]
)
```